# Write a Kolmogorov Complexity Solver

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, metagolf

The [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) of a string *S* is the length of the shortest program *P*, written in some programming language *L*, whose output is exactly *S*.
<sub>(Yes, the real definition is more formal but this will suffice for the challenge.)</sub>

Your task in this challenge is to write the shortest possible "Kolmogorov complexity solver", that is, a program written in *L* itself that takes in a string *S* and returns the shortest *P* written in *L* that outputs *S*.

The naive approach to this is to iterate over all length 1 programs, then all length 2 programs, then all length 3 programs, and so on, running each of them and measuring the output until a program that outputs *S* is found. The issue with this approach is that some of these programs may never stop running, which means that the solver itself may never stop. And due to [the halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) there is no surefire way to avoid the programs that don't stop.

A simple, though imperfect solution is to put a time limit on the execution time of each of the potential *P*'s. Programs that don't happen to halt in time may be passed over, but the solver will definitely stop (assuming that a program in *L* can indeed output *S* within the time limit).

## Challenge

Write your solver as a program or function that takes in three things:

- The string *S*.
- A positive integer *T* that is the time limit in seconds or some smaller time span (e.g. milliseconds).
- A string *A* of the alphabet of characters to use for potential *P*'s.

And outputs the shortest *P* that only contains characters in *A*, runs in less than *T* time units, and outputs *S*.

This is the general pseudocode:

```
Function KolmogorovComplexitySolver(S, T, A):
    Assign N to 0
    Loop until function returns:
        In any order, iterate over all strings of length N that only contain characters from *A*. Call the current string P:
            Execute P, saving the output to O, stopping the execution if it takes longer than time T
            If (P did not throw any errors) and (P did not timeout) and (O and S are identical):
                Return P
        Add 1 to N
```

## Details

- You may assume that there will always be a *P* made from the characters in *A* that runs in time *T* that outputs *S*.
- You may assume that the execution of the potential *P*'s will not have side effects that prevent the solver from running or working correctly (like messing with the solver's allocated memory).
- You may *not* assume that the potential *P*'s are error free. Be sure to include `try`/`catch` blocks or whatever applicable around the execution call.
- If there are multiple shortest *P*'s, then any will suffice. "Shortness" is measured in characters not bytes.
- The output of potential *P*'s is what's printed to stdout (or your language's usual output area). The empty string is a potential *P*.
- Ideally your solver will allow *A* to contain any characters. *A* must at least to be able to contain [printable ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) characters plus tabs and newlines.
- Input may come from file/stdin/command line/function args. Output goes to stdout or similar, or can be returned as a string if you wrote a function.

## Scoring

The submission with the [fewest bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter) wins. Tiebreaker goes to earliest posted submission.

Comment: My brain hurts.

Comment: Can you relax the requirement that the target language and language which the meta solver is written in must be the same?

Comment: And wouldn't it be possible to just write a program which converts the output into string literal representation of the language?

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳  No, the point is to do it in the same language. Yes, but that would not always be the shortest program.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies: So in the end, it is only a code golf challenge to find out which language can easily write code to call facilities (or implement compiler where absent) to compile the language itself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Python 3, <s>240</s> 236 bytes

```py
import subprocess as s,itertools as i
def f(S,T,A,N=0):
 while 1:
  for P in i.product(A,repeat=N):
   try:
    P="".join(P);open("a","w").write(P)
    if s.check_output(["py","-3","a"],timeout=T).decode()==S:return P
   except:1
  N+=1
```

**Don't run this.** On my computer, at least, I found the program really hard to stop once it started running due to the pop-up windows created per process.

`timeout`s were only added to `subprocess.check_output` in Python 3, which is why we're using this rather than Python 2.

Here's an alternative version with a `time.sleep` that also prints all valid programs found along the way, as well as their corresponding output:

```py
import subprocess as s,itertools as i
import time
def f(S,T,A,N=0):
 while 1:
  for P in i.product(A,repeat=N):
   time.sleep(0.2)
   try:
    P="".join(P);open("a","w").write(P);C=s.check_output(["py","-3","a"],timeout=T).decode()
    print(P,repr(C))
    if C==S:return P
   except:1
  N+=1
```

The program uses the filename `a` for each program `P` to be tested, so if you run this make sure you don't already have a file of that name. Replace `["py","-3","a"]` with the appropriate command for your setup (e.g. `["python","a"]` or `["python3","a"]`).

Feel free to change the `sleep` duration at your own risk :). Call like `f("1\r\n",1,"1()print")`, where `T` is timeout in seconds.

First few lines of output from the tester with the above call:

```py
 ''
1 ''
11 ''
() ''
111 ''
(1) ''
int ''
1111 ''
```

<sup>(If you want to help the program along a bit  you can change `P="".join(P)` to `P="print"+"".join(P)`)</sup>

Since the above programs all have no output, here's the result for `f("1\r\n",1,["print","(",")","1"])` (tokens aren't part of the challenge, but I wanted to show what happens):

```py
 ''
print ''
1 ''
() ''
11 ''
print() '\r\n'
(print) ''
(1) ''
111 ''
print(print) '<built-in function print>\r\n'
print(1) '1\r\n'
```

The return value is the string `'print(1)'`.

Finally, just for fun, here's what happens if the alphabet is `string.printable`, i.e.

```py
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c
```

[Pastebin link of all valid 0-2 char Python 3 programs](http://pastebin.com/jXNYm36c)